# Screen Resolution Settings not Working after NVIDIA Driver Update

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, display-resolution, gpu

[image: driver update nvidia]

I've installed the `nvidia-driver-415` through Software & Updates for my Dual GTX 970s. After restarting, my screen resolution is now stuck at 1024x 768 pixels. I've got two monitors, and now only one is working.

[image: display settings]

I also notice that my PC makes a lot more noise now. There are also some weird glitches with overlapping windows.

Here are my system specs:

[image: system]

I would really appreciate your help! I am tired of reinstalling Ubuntu just to fix this silly issue.

By the way: The issue persists even when setting the driver back to X.org S server - Nouveau display driver from xserver-xorg-vidoe-nouveau (open source).

```
pc                          
    description: Desktop Computer
    product: All Series (All)
    vendor: ASUS
    version: System Version
    serial: System Serial Number
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.8 dmi-2.8 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: administrator_password=disabled boot=normal chassis=desktop family=ASUS MB frontpanel_password=disabled keyboard_password=disabled power-on_password=disabled sku=All uuid=E0793C6E-DAD7-DD11-9494-2C56DC3B29F0
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: Z97-PRO GAMER
       vendor: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
       physical id: 0
       version: Rev X.0x
       serial: 151158190004513
       slot: To be filled by O.E.M.
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: 2202
          date: 12/08/2015
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 8128KiB
          capabilities: pci apm upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 45
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 16GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0,6 ns)
             product: 99U5471-054.A00LF
             vendor: Kingston
             physical id: 0
             serial: 982F213E
             slot: DIMM_A1
             size: 8GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: DIMM [empty]
             product: [Empty]
             vendor: [Empty]
             physical id: 1
             serial: [Empty]
             slot: DIMM_A2
        *-bank:2
             description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0,6 ns)
             product: 99U5471-054.A00LF
             vendor: Kingston
             physical id: 2
             serial: 9B340498
             slot: DIMM_B1
             size: 8GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
        *-bank:3
             description: DIMM [empty]
             product: [Empty]
             vendor: [Empty]
             physical id: 3
             serial: [Empty]
             slot: DIMM_B2
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790K CPU @ 4.00GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 52
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790K CPU @ 4.00GHz
          slot: SOCKET 1150
          size: 4256MHz
          capacity: 4400MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts flush_l1d cpufreq
          configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=8
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 53
             slot: CPU Internal L1
             size: 256KiB
             capacity: 256KiB
             capabilities: synchronous internal write-back
             configuration: level=1
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 54
             slot: CPU Internal L2
             size: 1MiB
             capacity: 1MiB
             capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=2
        *-cache:2
             description: L3 cache
             physical id: 55
             slot: CPU Internal L3
             size: 8MiB
             capacity: 8MiB
             capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=3
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 06
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=hsw_uncore
          resources: irq:0
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
             version: 06
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:16 ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:f6000000-f70fffff ioport:e0000000(size=301989888)
           *-display UNCLAIMED
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: GM204 [GeForce GTX 970]
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: a1
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
                configuration: latency=0
                resources: memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
           *-multimedia
                description: Audio device
                product: GM204 High Definition Audio Controller
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0.1
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
                version: a1
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
                resources: irq:17 memory:f7080000-f7083fff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x8 Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.1
             version: 06
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:16 ioport:d000(size=4096) memory:f4000000-f50fffff ioport:c0000000(size=301989888)
           *-display UNCLAIMED
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: GM204 [GeForce GTX 970]
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                version: a1
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller cap_list
                configuration: latency=0
                resources: memory:f4000000-f4ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:d000(size=128) memory:f5000000-f507ffff
           *-multimedia
                description: Audio device
                product: GM204 High Definition Audio Controller
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0.1
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.1
                version: a1
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
                resources: irq:18 memory:f5080000-f5083fff
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: 9 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 00
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:24 memory:f5120000-f512ffff
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: 9 Series Chipset Family ME Interface #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 00
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:27 memory:f513a000-f513a00f
        *-network
             description: Ethernet interface
             product: Ethernet Connection (2) I218-V
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 19
             bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
             logical name: eno1
             version: 00
             serial: 2c:56:dc:3b:29:f0
             size: 100Mbit/s
             capacity: 1Gbit/s
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
             configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.1-4 ip=192.168.2.109 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
             resources: irq:26 memory:f5100000-f511ffff memory:f5138000-f5138fff ioport:f040(size=32)
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: 9 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI Controller #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:f5137000-f51373ff
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: 9 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 00
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:28 memory:f5130000-f5133fff
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 9 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: d0
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:16
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 82801 PCI Bridge
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
             version: d0
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm subtractive_decode bus_master cap_list
           *-pci
                description: PCI bridge
                product: ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge
                vendor: ASMedia Technology Inc.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
                version: 04
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pci subtractive_decode bus_master cap_list
                resources: iomemory:202001f10-202001f0f
        *-usb:2
             description: USB controller
             product: 9 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:23 memory:f5136000-f51363ff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: Z97 Chipset LPC Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             resources: irq:0
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: 9 Series Chipset Family SATA Controller [AHCI Mode]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:25 ioport:f090(size=8) ioport:f080(size=4) ioport:f070(size=8) ioport:f060(size=4) ioport:f020(size=32) memory:f5135000-f51357ff
        *-serial
             description: SMBus
             product: 9 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 00
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: driver=i801_smbus latency=0
             resources: irq:18 memory:f5134000-f51340ff ioport:f000(size=32)
     *-scsi:0
          physical id: 1
          logical name: scsi0
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: KINGSTON SV300S3
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: BBF0
             serial: 50026B775300005A
             size: 223GiB (240GB)
             capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
             configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=d0fcebee-9248-48d6-bf8b-f8ef76ce1137 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
           *-volume:0 UNCLAIMED
                description: Windows FAT volume
                vendor: mkfs.fat
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                version: FAT32
                serial: 63bd-1303
                size: 510MiB
                capacity: 511MiB
                capabilities: boot fat initialized
                configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat name=EFI System Partition
           *-volume:1
                description: EXT4 volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sda2
                logical name: /
                version: 1.0
                serial: ad8896de-347c-461a-b945-fbb2904acffc
                size: 223GiB
                capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                configuration: created=2018-12-29 14:27:23 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2019-01-04 20:28:11 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro mounted=2019-01-04 20:28:11 state=mounted
     *-scsi:1
          physical id: 2
          logical name: scsi2
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: WDC WD10EZEX-00B
             vendor: Western Digital
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sdb
             version: 1A01
             serial: WD-WCC3F7YE265Y
             size: 931GiB (1TB)
             capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
             configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096 signature=3d384c52
           *-volume
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sdb1
                version: 3.1
                serial: 44ef7831-2b6b-104e-b5c0-e97a229b6fd0
                size: 931GiB
                capacity: 931GiB
                capabilities: primary ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2017-06-26 19:31:07 filesystem=ntfs label=HDD modified_by_chkdsk=true mounted_on_nt4=true resize_log_file=true state=dirty upgrade_on_mount=true
     *-scsi:2
          physical id: 3
          logical name: scsi5
          capabilities: emulated
        *-cdrom
             description: DVD-RAM writer
             product: DVDRAM GH24NSC0
             vendor: HL-DT-ST
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@5:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/cdrom
             logical name: /dev/cdrw
             logical name: /dev/dvd
             logical name: /dev/dvdrw
             logical name: /dev/sr0
             version: LK00
             capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
             configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
     *-scsi:3
          physical id: 4
          bus info: usb@4:5
          logical name: scsi6
          capabilities: emulated scsi-host
          configuration: driver=usb-storage
        *-disk
             description: SCSI Disk
             product: My Passport 0830
             vendor: WD
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@6:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sdc
             version: 1065
             serial: WX51A940N3YX
             size: 1862GiB (2TB)
             capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
             configuration: ansiversion=6 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 signature=7461523b
           *-volume
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@6:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sdc1
                logical name: /media/flo/NAME
                version: 3.1
                serial: 1451a945-afbe-b94a-a19c-dee4fdfc8cc8
                size: 1862GiB
                capacity: 1862GiB
                capabilities: primary ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2011-09-03 03:27:47 filesystem=ntfs label=NAME mount.fstype=fuseblk mount.options=rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 state=mounted
        *-enclosure UNCLAIMED
             description: SCSI Enclosure
             product: SES Device
             vendor: WD
             physical id: 0.0.1
             bus info: scsi@6:0.0.1
             version: 1065
             serial: WX51A940N3YX
             configuration: ansiversion=6
     *-scsi:4
          physical id: 5
          bus info: usb@3:6
          logical name: scsi7
          capabilities: emulated scsi-host
          configuration: driver=usb-storage
        *-disk:0
             description: SCSI Disk
             product: SD/MMC
             vendor: Generic-
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@7:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sdd
             version: 1.00
             capabilities: removable
             configuration: logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
           *-medium
                physical id: 0
                logical name: /dev/sdd
        *-disk:1
             description: SCSI Disk
             product: Compact Flash
             vendor: Generic-
             physical id: 0.0.1
             bus info: scsi@7:0.0.1
             logical name: /dev/sde
             version: 1.01
             capabilities: removable
             configuration: logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
           *-medium
                physical id: 0
                logical name: /dev/sde
        *-disk:2
             description: SCSI Disk
             product: SM/xD-Picture
             vendor: Generic-
             physical id: 0.0.2
             bus info: scsi@7:0.0.2
             logical name: /dev/sdf
             version: 1.02
             capabilities: removable
             configuration: logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
           *-medium
                physical id: 0
                logical name: /dev/sdf
        *-disk:3
             description: SCSI Disk
             product: MS/MS-Pro
             vendor: Generic-
             physical id: 0.0.3
             bus info: scsi@7:0.0.3
             logical name: /dev/sdg
             version: 1.03
             serial: 3
             capabilities: removable
             configuration: logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
           *-medium
                physical id: 0
                logical name: /dev/sdg
  *-power UNCLAIMED
       description: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       product: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       vendor: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       physical id: 1
       version: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       capacity: 32768mWh
```

Comment: We're going to need more details of your hardware configuration, so run `sudo lshw` and paste the details at the bottom of your post (by editing it) in a code block.
Also, please, don't just post screenshots of your config (or at all, unnecessarily), it slows down parsing your question, and means that others with a similar issue won't get a text match when doing a google search. I get that it is faster for you but it reduces the efficacy of your question for you, too.

Comment: Okay I dit it. And you're totally right, sorry.

Comment: No apology necessary. The short-term quick-fix reality will likely be to reinstall Ubuntu and live with the generic driver, I'm afraid.

Comment: Isn't there at least a way to revert the changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Quick Update

For me, updating to Ubuntu 19 seem to fix the issues.

Answer (score 0):

About my own experience,

I am using **nvidia-driver-390** and

I don't have any resolution problem on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installed Asus X550VX (GeForce GTX 950M) laptop.

You can try to downgrade to **nvidia-driver-390** driver version.

[image]

[image]