# Ubuntu 18.04 Login Screen Blank Unless External Monitor Plugged In

Tags: boot, login, multiple-monitors

I am having an issue with my laptop where the login screen only shows if an external monitor is plugged in. When I turn on the power:

1. The Grub menu appears (I have dual boot with Windows)
2. If I select Ubuntu then it shows the purple loading screen with the Ubuntu logo
3. The screen turns black (not even back lighting).
4. If I press enter and type in my password like I normally would at the login screen, the back lighting turns on, and then my home screen shows
   and everything works fine.

If I do this with an external monitor plugged in, then in step 3 the login screen shows on my laptop monitor and I can log in.

If I start with my monitor unplugged, wait for the screen to go black in step 3 then plug in the monitor, the login screen appears.

When I lock the computer the login appears: the problem only happens when booting up.

I tried deleting my `~/.config/monitors.xml` file but that didn't work. Any other suggestions?

**System Information**
 - Linux 18.04.1
 - Kernel 4.15.0-43-generic
 - Computer: ASUS Transformer Book Flip TP500LA (https://www.asus.com/2-in-1-PCs/ASUS_Transformer_Book_Flip_TP500LA/)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use "Integrated Intel® HD Graphics 4400" proprietary graphics driver over "Software & Updates" setting menu as shown in [Screen Resolution Settings not Working after NVIDIA Driver Update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1107013/screen-resolution-settings-not-working-after-nvidia-driver-update/1109604#1109604)

Comment: There is no option to do this sorry, it tells me I have no proprietary drivers available.